# PostgreSQL requirements for multi workstations

Tags: postgresql, installation

Can PostgreSQL run on network environment?  Does it required a dedicate machine to host the PostgreSQL engine, like MS SQL?

What am I trying to do is having multiple workstations can access to the network database at the same time, without connect to dedicated host machine.  The MS SQL Express doesn't allow me to put the database to network drive.

Comment: "like SQL"? SQL is a language, not a DBMS.

Comment: Besides that, the question is not clear? Are you asking if Postgres can run in a VM?

Comment: Or perhaps, you're asking if PostgreSQL requires a server to run (as opposed to, say, MS Access)? Please clarify your question.

Comment: "like SQL" doens't make sense. Postgres uses SQL as their query language - just like every other relational database

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PostgreSQL is fully network aware. You can put it on a separate machine or not, this all depends on how you use it, so you will need to state your requirements, type and volume of data, etc.

See for example https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html

For development purposes, you can install it on your own machine to develop your programs and later just move your application to use the production database.

Answer (score 0):

> Can PostgreSQL run on network environment?

Absolutely.  You will need to understand the pg_hba.conf file (amongst others) to allow 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Also consider cloud database products (AWS RDS, Azure, Google Cloud etc) that provide hosted database solutions including PostgreSQL.  These rely on networks to function otherwise they would be databases nothing could talk to.

> Does it required a dedicate machine to host the PostgreSQL engine, like SQL?

No (and for that matter neither does SQL Server).  Like anything there are recommended and best practices. And running database servers on dedicated hosts is one of those in most circumstances.  In a development environment you would very likely run the database server on your own machine along with all your application code.  Your test environment would probably separate the database to its own server to closely mirror what you would have in production.